# Showing hyperlinked reverse foreign key in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models

```
class Transaction(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Stores transaction details
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

and

```
class OrderDetail(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Model to store the order details at time of payment
    """
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(payment_models.Transaction, null=True, blank=True)
    order_amount = models.FloatField()
```

It is possible that two OrderDetails have same transaction linked. I want a link in my Transaction detail admin to all the orders that are linked to that transaction. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try this

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('order_details')

    def form_url(self, id):
        url = reverse("admin:reverse_url", args=[id])
        return '<a href=%s>%s</a>'%(url, id)

    def order_details(self, obj):

        return "<br>".join([self.form_url(k.id) for k in obj.orderdetail_set.all()])

    order_details.allow_tags=True
    form_url.allow_tags=True
```

Comment: Please provide explanation of which part of your code works for OP.  This would be helpful to the people who read your answer in future.